# Mostrar Elementos obtenidos de BD mediante Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, phpmyadmin

¿A que se debe que no se muestren correctamente mis registros de la BD en Frontend?.

Lo primero que hago es obtenerlos de la BD mediante PHP de la siguiente manera.

**Código PHP**

```
$result2 = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM curso");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
 /*Mostrando fecha de los Cursos */
 echo '<div id="imagelist"">';
 echo '
     <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-danger">'.$row['fechaLimite'].'</h5>
     <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" id="countdown"></h6>';
 echo '</div>';
}
```

Codigo JQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var recorrido = $("h5").each(function(){

      fecha = ($(this).text());

      $("h6").text(fecha);

    });
  });
</script>
```

Lo que necesito hacer es una cuenta regresiva por eso opte por poner Código Jquery. Necesito que me muestre los datos obtenidos en el h5, y los muestre en el h6. Lo único que me muestra es siempre el último registro. He intentado cambiando append() por text()

```
$("h6").append(fecha);
```

pero me muestra todos los registros de corrido y obviamente no los puedo ocupar.Lo que quiero es que me muestre uno por uno y poder hacer uso de ellos.

Comment: Tu código jQuery esta capturando lo que metes en h6 para meterlo a h7, no es mejor que entonces hagas esto $row['fechaLimite'] dentro de h7 a ya? no entiendo del todo tu pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que pones `$('h7').text(fecha)`, estás indicando que todos los `h7` editen su texto.
Para indicar que solo quieres editar el h7 a continuación tendría que ser

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var recorridoh6 = $("h6").each(function(){

    fecha = ($(this).text());

    $(this).closest('div').find('h7').text(fecha);

  });
});
```

Esta respuesta responde el porqué ocurre lo que te pasa, y creo era importante entender el porqué, pero como menciona @Beder Paisa en el comentario tu pregunta sería mucho más sencillo ponerlo directamente cuando iteras con php

```
$result2 = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM curso");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {/*Mostrando fecha de los Cursos */
echo '<div id="imagelist"">';
echo '
  <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-danger">'.$row['fechaLimite'].'</h6>
  <h7 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" id="countdown">'.$row['fechaLimite'].'</h7>
';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Quedó resuelta mi duda. Lo ocupo así porque como mencioné antes. La fecha que estoy obteniendo la ocuparé para hacer una cuenta regresiva en tiempo real en JQuery. :)